# write complex<double>'s to plain text/binary file in C++, and read them into a NumPy array

Tags: python, c++, numpy, io, binary-data

TLDR:

1. How do I read a plain text file of (Re, Im) tuples (arranged in rows and columns) into a NumPy array of complex numbers, respecting the row-column structure of the text file?
2. How do I do the same for binary files that I write in C++ and read into a NumPy array, if possible communicating the row-column structure directly?

Details:

I'm running physics simulations in a C++ code, and doing the data analysis in Python. I am dealing with arrays of type `complex<double>` (actually [armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) `cx_mat` matrices; I don't think this is relevant to my problem but it might be).

I need to write such an array, of shape `Nt` rows and `Nx` columns, into a file, and then read it into a numpy array of complex doubles, of the same shape.

Minimal working example: I have the following C++ code to output the data, as a plain text file, or as a binary file (I will need to use binary when `Nt` and `Nx` get very large).

```cpp
  //data is in my_cx_double_arr
  
  //write data to plain txt file                                                                                                                                                              
  ofstream txt_fout_stream("txt_output.txt" , ios::out | ios::app);
  txt_fout_stream << scientific;
  txt_fout_stream.precision(12);
  for(int i=0; i<Nt; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<Nx; j++){
      txt_fout_stream << my_cx_double_arr(i,j) << " ";
    }
    txt_fout_stream << endl;
  }
  txt_fout_stream.close();

  //write data to binary file                                                                                                                                                                 
  ofstream bin_fout_stream("bin_output.bin", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
  for(int i=0; i<Nt; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<Nx; j++){
      bin_fout_stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>( &my_cx_double_arr(i,j) ) , sizeof(complex<double>));
      }
    }
  bin_fout_stream.close();
```

My questions:

1. `txt_output.txt` is formatted as an array of tuples of the correct shape, e.g.:

```
(5.610842645053e-02,-5.700807222085e-01) (-1.198577806951e+00,9.814201723115e-01) 
(5.016283876502e-01,-1.965153563607e-01) (-2.629706723344e-01,1.228331874675e+00) 
(-2.431860857327e-01,-3.638485210072e-01) (-3.030812460688e-01,7.194149378419e-01)
```

How do I read this into a NumPy array of complex numbers, with each tuple reading into z=(Re,Im), and the array has the same `Nt` rows and `Nx` cols as in the text file?

2. How do I read this into a similar NumPy array if I write to a binary file instead? Also, is there a way to write the binary file to encode the row-column structure? (I'm guessing not; if not then I will have `Nt` and `Nx` available in my NumPy script)
3. (Any tips on proper file handling/error checking would be greatly appreciated, although my main questions are 1. and 2.)

I'm sure this has been answered before, so sorry if this it has. (I have searched, but searching this question suffers from many confounding factors, e.g. "complex" being synonymous with "complicated"!)

*Addendum:* I'm aware that writing/reading binary files is platform dependent. I will write and read on the same machine, but I'm interested in learning a how to work around this, although it's not my main question. Likewise I haven't included any error handling of files, but would like to learn what good practice is once the main questions are solved!

Comment: Not tested but you could have a look at this https://github.com/rogersce/cnpy/blob/master/cnpy.h - This basically lets you create a `.npy` file from C++ that you can then load with `numpy.load` with all the checking you need.

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with Armadaillo, but [this](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#save_load_mat) suggest you can save matrix in CSV or HDF5 format, so you can probably load them from numpy using `pandas` or `h5py` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks Holt. I don't know anything about HDF5 but it does seem like a good solution. I would like to learn how to deal with raw binary files in NumPy first, but the HDF5 route does seem like it would be useful...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looks like the answer to 2. was super easy.

```py
import numpy as np

fname = open('bin_output.bin')
data_in = np.fromfile( fname, dtype=np.complex_, count =-1)
fname.close()
data_reshaped = np.reshape(data_in, (Nt,Nx))
```

The numbers in `data_reshaped` match exactly the numbers in the human-readable file `txt_output.txt`.

However this doesn't appear to be the answer for 1. The same method applied to `txt_output.txt` gives an array `data_in` that is of a totally different shape, and has totally different numbers (with wildly different orders of magnitude) than what is actually in the file `txt_output.txt`.

Bizarre!